# Accessing cache directory of all apps on iDevice

Tags: ios, file-management

Is there any way to access cache directory for all applications on an iDevice programmatically? For clarification, I know the way to access the cache directory for a specific app, but does there exist a default directory that stores all caches the iDevice?

Comment: No, you can't. Your app runs in sandbox, which you are limited to your App's directory.

Comment: [Is it even possible for one iOS app to access another app's caches directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5954040)